# Bash: listining the pressed key while being in another window/application

Tags: bash

my problem is, I coded a bash-script for a stop-timer for speedruns (like livesplit). The Timer is working, but I*d like to operate the script with a hotkey while I am using another apllication/window. (the concrete Problem is, I need a method for asking within a if-loop if a certain button is pressed, it has to work while I am in another application.

thanks in advance,
Nulli

Comment: You will need to register a listener to the key events to record it so your loop picks it up, or read the current input device state every time you wake. This may help 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217191/sending-key-press-signals-to-a-background-process

Comment: how? I am not the best in bash

Comment: That is not a bash question anymore :). You will need to learn more about the kernel to know what is available to you to read or get an interupt/message when something happens to an input device. In linux  everything is a file :) input device events are in /dev/input folder as events files. or something .

Comment: OK thx :):):):):):)